# dispatcherservlet does not wire model to view

Tags: spring

I made a model from a controller and return to dispatcherservlet. It looks like there is no problem

in model since I double checked output by system.out.println. for viewname string, I double checked

an actual directory name which is "WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp".

but I believe dispatcher servlet does not adapt model to a view since browser does not displayed

a model value which should be displayed. It would be easier to understand what I am going through

if I put my code here. so... here is my code.

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd"
>
<context:annotation-config/>
<bean name="/hello" class="com.spring.toby.HelloController"/>
<bean id="HelloSpring" class="com.spring.toby.HelloSpring"></bean>  
</beans>
```

and controller java file

```
public class HelloController implements Controller{

@Autowired HelloSpring helloSpring;
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String msg = this.helloSpring.sayHello(name);
    System.out.println(msg);
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("msg", msg);
    return new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp", model);
}
}
```

and bean file

```
public class HelloSpring {
public String sayHello(String name){
    return "Hello " + name;
}
}
```

and jsp file

```
</head>
    <body>
    <div><h1>Testing</h1></div>
    ${message}
    </body>
```

can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting??
Can you shouw the error console or attach some screen shot here?

Comment: no.. I am not getting an error. oh.. I forgot attaching jsp file here. If you look at my jsp file you could understand my problem.

Comment: Ok then go ahead. Please show your jsp code also.

Comment: ${message} should be changed as "hello " + requestparam but looks like view is not reconizing a model.. oh wait... do I have a typo there? let me check. I will fix message to name

Comment: Yes its a typo. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a silly mistake.

Please replace **${message}** in your jsp with **${msg}** and you will get the message printed in your jsp.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Comment: ah.. thx.. It is always simple error that makes me spend too much time.

Comment: Yea... It happens to me also sometimes. Its just because of excessive amount of time spend while working. Go and get some rest. :D